# How do I fix cracking sounds?

Tags: audio, retropie

I have installed RetroPie in my B+, but when I play a game, the sound cracks. I have connect my speakers using 3,5 mm jack.

Comment: First, because of the nature of the jack(for video and audio out) I have learned that you have to put it in a certain way(you cant plug it in all the way). Also, speakers have impeadence values and will max out so check your volume.

Comment: This article talks about sound quality on the b+: http://www.crazy-audio.com/2014/07/sound-quality-of-the-raspberry-pi-b/ and suggests one of these http://www.hifiberry.com/dacplus after concluding the sound on the B+ was not that good.

Comment: @NULL If I plug my headphone into the Pi I don't have cracking sounds. And if I plug my speakers into another computer I don't have the cracking sounds.

Comment: The jack on the pi is different from that on your computer: the computer is only meant for headphones whereas the pi has more contacts so you have to stick it in farther or less possibly. Otherwise I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three solutions for this:

### Solution 1

Make sure your Pi is getting enough power. This is the most common problem with Raspberry Pi's, because they don't come with a standardized power supply. Just make sure you are using a **thick and short** cord, and not a thin and long one like phone charging cords.

### Solution 2

Pulseaudio. Pulseaudio is a package for the RPi that significantly increases the quality of the audio. Follow [this tutorial](https://dbader.org/blog/crackle-free-audio-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-mpd-and-pulseaudio).

### Solution 3

Buy an external USB sound card. This is what I do, just because I needed to record things and the RPi's audio jack is not capable of input. I use [this card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M3UWE3Q), it is very cheap at $3 and the quality exactly the same as the audio port on my Macbook.

Comment: While an older solution, worth mentioning that the OP mentioned running RetroPie.  While Pulseaudio works great under Raspbian, in general, there are some reports of system hangs on RetroPie.  I recently ran into freezing with Pulseaudio on an otherwise vanilla RetroPie image, twice.  For anyone pursuing solution two on a RetroPie, who then experiences freezes, uninstalling Pulseaudio will get you back to even keel, most likely.

Comment: Pulse Audio does **NOT** significantly increase the quality of the audio.  PERIOD.

It adds software mixing and network sound server capability.  The problem is that it injects 100+ msec of latency on playback and it can do screwed up things like scratch sound over time because of POOR coding work.

Answer (score 0):

If others are having this problem on a Raspberry Pi 1: Upgrade your firmware with `rpi-update` - see https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/128

That reduces the number of cracks to 1, on the first use.