# Sound glitch when playing video with Pi 3 and omxplayer

Tags: audio, omxplayer

I am watching a video on my Raspberry Pi using omxplayer. But sometimes my TV audio output makes a hard sounding glitch, a ("ghrrr") sound randomly.

Does somebody know how I can fix this? The video format that I am using is H264:HD1080p 29.97fps.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the nature of the Pi's audio port. There are a few ways to fix or improve the audio quality, as shown in my answer to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32356/how-do-i-fix-cracking-sounds/36156#36156).