# ALSA channels count error while using simpleaudio with USB DAC

Tags: alsa

Here is the code:

```
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("sounds/2c.wav")
wave_obj.play()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:7924:(snd_pcm_set_params) Channels count (1) not available for PLAYBACK: Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gpio.py", line 11, in <module>
wave_obj.play()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py", line 20, in play
self.bytes_per_sample, self.sample_rate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py", line 61, in play_buffer
sample_rate)
_simpleaudio.SimpleaudioError: Error setting parameters. -- CODE: -22 -- MSG: Invalid argument
```

I'm trying to use a USB audio connector for audio out because I've heard it [improves crackling](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36156/33625).  The library for sound playing I'm using is [simpleaudio](http://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).  Is this an issue with ALSA or simpleaudio, and how can I fix it?

Asked for in comments:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $  ~/.asoundrc
-bash: /home/pi/.asoundrc: Permission denied
pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ sudo  ~/.asoundrc
sudo: /home/pi/.asoundrc: command not found


pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ ls
adduser.conf            environment        ldap            opt              security
alternatives            esound             ld.so.cache     os-release       selinux
apache2                 fake-hwclock.data  ld.so.conf      PackageKit       services
apm                     fb.modes           ld.so.conf.d    pam.conf         sgml
apparmor.d              fonts              ld.so.preload   pam.d            shadow
apt                     fstab              libaudit.conf   passwd           shadow-
avahi                   fuse.conf          libnl-3         passwd-          shells
bash.bashrc             gai.conf           libreoffice     perl             skel
bash_completion         gconf         


pi@raspberrypi:/ $ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ cat /etc/asound.conf
cat: /etc/asound.conf: No such file or directory
```

aplay

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/gpio $ aplay -v sounds/2c.wav
Playing WAVE 'sounds/2c.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1239: Channels count non available
pi@raspberrypi:~/gpio $ aplay -v -D plughw sounds/2c.wav
Playing WAVE 'sounds/2c.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
Plug PCM: Hardware PCM card 0 'bcm2835 ALSA' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 22050
  period_size  : 5512
  period_time  : 124988
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 5512
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 22050
  stop_threshold   : 22050
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1445068800
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
```

Comment: Show the `/etc/asound.conf` and `~/.asoundrc` files.

Comment: I couldn't find either of those, see edit to post

Comment: Just show the contents: `cat /etc/asound.conf`.

Comment: I'm not finding anything.  No file or directory, added an edit to post.

Comment: What is the output of `aplay -v sounds/2c.wav` and `aplay -v -D plughw sounds/2c.wav`?

Comment: added aplay calls

Comment: so, I found a "fix."  apparently mono .wav files don't play nice, so I got some stereo ones instead.  I hate python.

Comment: The default device should be able to automatically convert the sample format (like `plughw` does). You do not appear to have a custom configuration for the ALSA devices, but it's possible that your distribution did something wrong there.

Comment: I really would like to know.  I'm thinking I might build Arch soon so I can maybe have a better idea of what's going on.